# Spark data frame write to Elastic Search using es-hadoop connector with aws role based signing

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am seeking for a connector/client in scala which sends signed requests to AWS elastic search. 
I've already used "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "6.3.0". 
This sends requests to aws elasticsearch without signing and they don't support signing requests. 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1140

working example will be much helpful

Thanks